# Facebook Link Debugger

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to post a link to my website on my Facebook, but it won't show a picture. I am using meta content tags, but I originally used a URL with "whitespace" and got this error:

> URL 'http://ixxx.photobucket.com/albums/b567/xxxxxxxxxx/Screen Shot 2015-04-29 at 10.15.44 AM_zpsofejd5mn.png' for property 'og:image:url' of the object at 'http://xxxxxxxxx.com/news/2015/4/30/studiomonthly_april' is invalid because it contains whitespace characters.

I have since updated the image URL to a different link, but when I fetch new scrape information it will only show me the old link. I've been doing this for hours! Please help!

Thank you for trying to help me!

Answer (score 1):

It's a temporary bug.

Facebook team is working on a fix:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978421888869140/